# Get result from two rown in two diffrent tabels mysql

Tags: mysql

This is from a football system, where every game, player and "log" for a game can be saved for statistics.

- "bold_players" is the table with the player: id, name, age...
- "bold_playlog" is the table with all the logs for the games: id, createdate, logtype, playerid...
  "logtype = 1" is a goal (only one goal — every goal will have one post/id on the table "bold_playlog", so if a game has four goals, there will be four posts in "bold_playlog" with the same gameid).

How can I get a list with all the players, ordered by goals?

Here is my code right now, but I think I have to join the two tables or something like that!?:

```
$data_player = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, goals, playtogoal FROM bold_players ORDER BY name ASC ");
while ($row_player = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_player)) {

$seasonstart = mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, date('Y')-1);

$logplayer = $row_player['id'];
$data_log = mysql_query("SELECT id, createdate, logtype FROM bold_playlog WHERE logplayer=$logplayer AND logtype = 1 AND createdate > $seasonstart ");
$getresult = mysql_num_rows($data_log);

if($getresult > 0) {

echo 'the result';

}}
```

Comment: "ordered by goals"... by the time of the first goal, or by the amount of goals or...?

Comment: Sorry! Is the amount of goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` should do it, this orders most goals first which would be the `DESC` part, use `ASC` for fewest goals first.

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.playerid) goals
FROM bold_players a
LEFT JOIN bold_log b
  ON b.playerid = a.id
 AND b.logtype=1
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.age
ORDER BY COUNT(b.playerid) DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8717/1).

If you also need more logtypes, you'll have to change the query somewhat. If `offside` is logtype 2, the query will be;

```
SELECT a.*, 
  COALESCE(SUM(b.logtype=1), 0) goals, 
  COALESCE(SUM(b.logtype=2), 0) offsides
FROM bold_players a
LEFT JOIN bold_log b
  ON b.playerid = a.id
-- AND (b.logtype=1 OR b.logtype=2)      -- for speedup if there are many types
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.age
ORDER BY COALESCE(SUM(b.logtype=1), 0) DESC
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/beed8/2).

Comment: Thanks, it looks great - and it works. What if I also want to get the count of "offside" also placed in `bold_log`? (is the count of offsides for every player)?

Comment: @LasseBoWamsler Updated the answer with the new info.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this.. I would guess it must be something like this

```
SELECT  name, goals, sum(playtogoal) as goals, createdate, logtype 
FROM bold_players as ps LEFT JOIN bold_playlog as pl ON ps.id=pl.logplayer
WHERE pl.logtype = 1 AND pl.createdate > $saesonstart
GROUP BY ps.id ORDER BY name ASC
```

I would make a LEFT JOIN since there could be players without a goal and they would be shown too